# Does Quickblox support Android GCM message proirity ?

Tags: message, quickblox

I have tried setting "data.priority" but the message seems top bounce between Qb and GCM. ?

I want to receive WakefulBroadcast when the phone is in Doze.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment all pushes are sent with the default priority and you can't manage this.

QuickBlox may open this API in near releases.